# How to style only FlatList content when it has Header

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm trying to make whole screen scrollable. So I need to make the area marked with red `ListHeaderComponent` and style the actual content area (add a bacgroundColor and shadow to it).
`columnWrapperStyle` is exactly what I need to use to accomplish the task. But it only works if `numColums > 1`.

Separating FlatList and Header, and wrapping them into a ScrollView is another option but *VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews with the same orientation.*

There are props to style Header and Footer but there is no way to style only the actual content.

So, How can I style only the content area?

[image: screenshot]